# Как выполнить задачи последовательно с ожиданием окончания предидущей

Tags: objective-c, ios

Как выполнить задачи последовательно с ожиданием окончания предидущей

```
    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    [self startActivityIndicator];

    dispatch_apply([self.filteredList count], queue, ^(size_t i) {
        PayDoc *payDoc = (PayDoc*)([self.filteredList objectAtIndex:i]);
        if (([payDoc.INFOR isEqualToString:@"V"])&&([payDoc.ACCPT isEqualToString:@"X"])){
            [self.tableList setVisa:payDoc andResult:@"V" andMess:@""];
             NSLog(@"%@ , %zu",[NSDate date], i);
        }
    });
```

Сейчас:

2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 0
 
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 1
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 2
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 4
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 3
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 6
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 5
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 9
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 7
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 10
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 11
2015-04-08 07:50:39 +0000 , 8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно попробовать запустить один асинхронный вызов и засунуть в него цикл. Зачем усложнять то?

```
[self startActivityIndicator];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    for (PayDoc *payDoc in self.filteredList) {
        if (([payDoc.INFOR isEqualToString:@"V"]) && ([payDoc.ACCPT isEqualToString:@"X"])) {
            [self.tableList setVisa:payDoc andResult:@"V" andMess:@""];
        }        
    }
    [self stopActivityIndicator];
};
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да я так пробовал. Мне нужно что бы выполнение было последовательным.

Comment: Цикл `for` перебирает элементы строго в том порядке, в котором они расположены в массиве. Видимо, вам нужно предварительно отсортировать массив.

Comment: В вызове выполняется апи запрос к серверу, а когда документов много не всегда успевает присвоить номер,некоторым документам одинаковые номера присваивает. Может делать задержку между вызовами в одну секунду?

Comment: Что-то явно не так. Зачем присваивать номер? Это должно делаться на сервере, приложение не может ничего знать о правильном порядке данных.

Comment: Та номер на SAP сервере и присваиваеться. Может там не успевает генерит номер документа.

Comment: В любом случае, дополнительные задержки в приложении - это плохой путь. Нельзя исправлять недоработки сервера костылями на клиенте :)

Comment: Да так и было, подправил на стороне SAP все нормально стало работать.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSOperationQueue *operationQueue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    operationQueue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
    [operationQueue addOperation:someOperation];
```

Comment: Вот так можно добиться последовательно выполнения! Надеюсь, что не нужно объяснять, как создать операцию?

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать использовать dispatch_group-ы

Что-то в роде:

```
       `dispatch_group_t someOperationGroup = dispatch_group_create();`
        dispatch_group_enter(someOperationGroup);
        //TODO: do some work
        if(finished){
            dispatch_group_leave(someOperationGroup);
        } callbackQueue:dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)];

        dispatch_group_wait(someOperationGroup, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER);
```